# NullReferenceException displays when I'm trying to activate camera effect

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

NullReferenceException displays when I'm trying to activate an effect on my main camera.

I have a tiny script on my main camera:

```
using UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {
    private SunShafts mySunShafts;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        mySunShafts = GetComponent<SunShafts>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        foreach (Camera c in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(Camera))) {
            if ((c.name == "Main Camera")) {
                if ((c.transform.position.x > 6000)) {
                    mySunShafts.enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Build process is sucessfull, but when I'm starting the scene, Console keeps saying the following:

[image]

...and my effect doesn't activate at all.

Why am I getting this exception and how could I resolve this issue?

========================== Edit #1 ==============================

I think that the script has already added to the Inspector tab. The screenshot below shows the Main Camera's Inspector tab.
(Red bar indicates my above mentioned script and the red arrow indicates the effect I'd like to activate)

[image]

Comment: Are  you sure you have a component Called sunshaft on that gameobject?
the error says null reference line 20, you only have mySunShaft at that line, which means it's null, the assigning to it in the start is returning null, which means no component recovered

Comment: You forgot to "drag the item in the inspector" to the slot. Also please note you can just use Camera.main.  Please google for a billion pages on this.

Comment: @Joe Blow please see Edit #1 section of my original question.

Comment: @Hassan Khallof: I have a component called "Sun Shafts (Script)" which is part of UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects;

Comment: Your component is disabled in the picture you posted, check the checkbox next to it and try again

Comment: Yes it is disabled since the main goal of my project is to write a script which can enable this effect. The purpose of the above mentioned script is to enable this effect. (Anyway I just tried the opposit way: I've just tried to enable (tick) the effect and change the script to disable this effect programatically but the above mentioned error still occures.)

Comment: Hi Fract.  You should simply follow a basic tutorial, click to Unity3d to instantly find Unity's amazing VIDEO TUTORIALS.  this site just is not for very basic back-and-fore instruction on naming classes and so on buddy.

Comment: You've got a reference to the sunshafts and looping round all the cameras every frame to enable a component, this is really inefficient. Just attach this script to your MainCamera only. Then correct your Update Method as below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're only interested in this behaviour on your main camera, so just attach the script to your main camera only.
Amends as follows, Using a foreach loop and Using `GameObject.Find` in an `Update` is inefficient and completely unnecessary here.

```
using UnityStandardAssets.ImageEffects;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraSunShafts : MonoBehaviour {
    private SunShafts mySunShafts;

    // Use Awake for setting up references to components.
    void Awake () {
        mySunShafts = GetComponent<SunShafts>();
    }

    void Update () {
        if (transform.position.x > 6000)
             mySunShafts.enabled = true;
    }
}
```

If you move your camera over 6000 units on it's X position it will enable the Sun Shafts